# Sharing Files Between Windows and Android over WiFi

Tags: android, windows, wifi, protocols

Is there a way ( protocol ?) to share & exchange files between pc with Windows os and a mobile phone with Android os  over WiFi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an Ad Hoc Android to PC connection (Per the source below):

1. Connect your computer with virtual hotspot created by Android device.
2. Install any FTP Server app on Android device. It'll NOT give you IP of device for sure.
3. In your computer, find IP of Default Gateway of Wi-Fi network of Step 1 (In Windows, you can use ipconfig cmd command). Its the IP of your device.
4. Use any FTP Client software on computer. Use `ftp://IP:Port` (Port is generally configurable in FTP server app). Enter username & password configured in FTP Server app. Done!

Then they said "After some testing with different settings I got it to work flawlessly, thank you very much. For anyone else looking to do this: I used [Android Wifi Tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/)  to start the network using Softap mode, connected to it with the computer, started an FTP server (some server apps might need you to enable 3G mode, even though 3G data isn't actually used, you can turn data connections off if you're paranoid."

[Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25898/how-to-transfer-files-over-wifi-without-a-hotspot)

---

For Internet Based Connections:

You may simply want to transfer the files to a hosted server with push notifications to "pull" down the files to the various devices.

Scope this out: http://www.eckstreme.net/

The coder of that app may be willing to help you get off to a better start, email him.

Comment: Thanks for the link , but this requires an internet connection as it uses a server as a medium , my question was about sharing file same way as it is between windows PCs

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. Connect your pc and android device to the same Wifi Network. This can be an ad-hoc network created on the android device or your home/work wifi network.
2. To create an ad-hoc network on your device go to Settings->More (under wireless networks)->Tethering & portable hotspot and tick the portable wifi hostspot option.
3. Install a FTP server app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver from android marketplace.
4. Start the app on the device and connect to the URL provided by the app from PC.
5. Transfer files to/from device from/to PC